# C++ Video Capturing using Sink Writer - Memory consumption

Tags: c++, firemonkey, c++builder, video-processing

I am writing a C++ program (Win64) using C++ Builder 11.1.5 that captures video from a web cam and stores the captured frames in a WMV file using the **sink writer** interface as described in the following tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/medfound/tutorial--using-the-sink-writer-to-encode-video?redirectedfrom=MSDN

The video doesn't need to be real time using 30 Frames per second as the process being recorded is a slow one so I have set the FPS to be 5 (which is fine.)

The recording needs to run for about 8-12 hours at a time and using the algorithms in the sink writer tutorial, I have seen the memory consumption of the program go up dramatically after 10 minutes of recording (in excess of 10 Gb of memory).  I also have seen that the final WMV file only becomes populated when the Finalize routine is called.  Because of the memory consumption, the program starts to slow down after a while.

**First Question:**  Is it possible to flush the sink writer to free up ram while it is recording?

**Second Question:**  Maybe it would be more efficient to save the video in pieces and finalize the recording every 10 minutes or so then start another recording using a different file name such that when 8 hours is done the program could combine all the saved WMV files?  How would one go about combining numerous WMV files into one large file?

Comment: Please, keep it to one question per question post. (Also, the problem of combining video files is definitely going to be covered somewhere already -- you probably don't even need to write code to do that, perhaps look at ffmpeg or something similar).

Comment: It might be the case that the encoding is not keeping up with the rate of input? Perhaps periodically inspecting (logging) the writer's [statistics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfreadwrite/ns-mfreadwrite-mf_sink_writer_statistics) might shed some more light on this? That said, I'd definitely go for producing shorter chunks that will be merged later. (For one it's less likely to lose it all if something goes wrong).

Comment: Dan,  The rate of input is 5 frames per second and this is on a Core-i9 (18 cores) with 128 GB RAM.  I am using a timer to run every 200 mSeconds where it grabs the frame from the web cam, then stuffs it into the sink writer.  It should be ok but it would be nice to flush it out to a file before the ram becomes too much to handle.  With 5 FPS, I find the resulting file is about 350 MB for 1 hour.  I originally had it running with uncompressed video but the files being generated were HUGE in size (about 500 MB for 10 seconds of video.)